# this != this in javascript (well, sometimes....)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example 1

```
var Reptile = function () {
  var reptile = this;
   this.showBla = function() {
       alert(reptile.bla);
   }
}

var turtle = new Reptile();
turtle.bla = 'whatever';
turtle.showBla();
```

Example 2

```
var Reptile = function () {
   this.showBla = function() {
       alert(this.bla);
   }
}

var turtle = new Reptile();
turtle.bla = 'whatever';
turtle.showBla();
```

Is example 1 legit? As it sometimes seems to screw things over to define "this" directly in the constructor...?!?

Comment: Looks just fine. You're not defining anything in the constructor, you just store a reference. No problem at all.

Comment: You cannot define `this` yourself. It's always available and cannot be overwritten.

Comment: Since both examples are bulletproof legit, can you provide the code that sometimes screws things over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is legit and is useful in cases where you may need to define a function inside a function that may be invoked in a way there "this" will pointer to something else. Books recommend naming this variable var that = this;

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is a common pattern for maintaining the reference to the current instance.  In a callback situation, like:

```
setTimeout(turtle.showBla, 0);
```

Example 1's `var reptile...` saves the `this` reference and  will show `'whatever'`.  Example 2 will show `undefined`, unless you manually assign scope on the calling side (e.g., in jQuery):

```
setTimeout($.proxy(turtle.showBla, turtle), 0);
```